# Auto Wrap - Text Object in Rave report

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, word-wrap, rave-reports

I'm a newbie,recently i use rave report 10.0BE on Delphi XE2,i have problem when preview report.

I have a text field too long ,when print lost some character ,because length of field 
 than width column on report ,i don't want additional width column because on report so much column, i want text field is set can grow and when data from database coming is too long,it's grows into next line.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Rave designer, use a memo control with Truncate set to False instead of a text control.

If you are writing your report in code (my preference), use a [TMemoBuf](http://www.nevrona.com/rave/tips/rvtip23.html).